# Android - Starting activity, can't reach OnCreate with extra

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable

I'm trying to pass a serialized array of objects from one activity to another.  However, I'm unable to reach OnCreate in the second activity if I attach the extra to the intent.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**From the first activity:**

```
public void onDisplayImages(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImagesActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(IMAGE_LIST,mImagesList);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

}
```

**This way doesn't work either:**

```
public void onDisplayImages(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImagesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(IMAGE_LIST,mImagesList);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

}
```

mImageList is an ArrayList of ImageData objects where ImageData extends Serializable.  When I don't attempt to attach the extra, I make it to the second activity.

ImageData:

```
public class ImageData implements Serializable {

public Bitmap mImage;
public String mName;

public ImageData(String fileName, Context context){

    mName = fileName;
    File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(fileName);
    try {
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

**Error:**

```
05-28 16:50:40.540 2731-2731/[myPackageName]/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: [myPackageName], PID: 2731 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity –
```

Comment: 05-28 16:50:40.540    2731-2731/[myPackageName]/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: [myPackageName], PID: 2731
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: Show the onCreate() of ImagesActivity too. And more of the stacktrace too.

Comment: It doesn't make it to onCreate() so that information is irrelevant.  I'm almost positive the issue is ImageData not being serialized correctly.  Think I'm breaking this rule: "Transient fields (with transient modifier) are NOT serialized, (i.e., not saved or restored). A class that implements Serializable must mark transient fields of classes that do not support serialization (e.g., a file stream)."  Not a lot of information on how to fix this.